# How To Implement Search Bar in iOS 7. Searching works fine but the resulting content loaded is not corresponds to the search result

Tags: ios, objective-c

**How to select the search result of table view instead of loading normal table view contents**

In my iOS project using `UISearchBar`. Searching works fine for me but in the time of selecting the search resulting row the did select row methods loading original items instead of the search resulting row. What method should I use for load the resultant row and its corresponding detail page.

Thanks,

code:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
     [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:      
     [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];    

     // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
     return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubCategory" sender:self];
}      

#pragma mark Content Filtering
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    //[self.filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
    filteredArray=[categoryNameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];     
}        

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
    [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:      
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}    

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUserDefaults *usr=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString*fontc=[usr stringForKey:@"fontchange"];
    float fontSize=[fontc floatValue];
    newfont= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
       cell.textLabel.text=[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
       cell.textLabel.text=[categoryNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font=newfont;
    UIImage *img;

    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_generic.png"];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.imageView.image=img;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @Larme i have posted all the code i have used as answer. hoping your help asap    -Thank you :)

Comment: In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` do the same that you did in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` : `if (tableView ==ZzZ){//Do Something}else{//Do other things}`

Comment: @Larme  sorry. but i didnt get what exactly want to do

Comment: @Larme. , i didn't get what exactly i want to do in    tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:   hoping a clear answer from u - thank you :)

Comment: @Saurabh Prajapati,   im using the same view controller to load the both result. then will it work this idea. expecting a clear answer asap -- thank you :)

Comment: Hey, what is that bounty about? Didn't the accepted answer convince you enough?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes

     [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:

     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:

      [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];    

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;}
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubCategory" sender:self]; 
}   
#pragma mark Content Filtering
    - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.

    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    //[self.filteredArray removeAllObjects];

    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];

    filteredArray=[categoryNameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; }        
#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
    - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:

     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:

      [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSUserDefaults *usr=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString*fontc=[usr stringForKey:@"fontchange"];
    float fontSize=[fontc floatValue];
    newfont= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
       cell.textLabel.text=[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else

    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[categoryNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    cell.textLabel.font=newfont;
    UIImage *img;

    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_generic.png"];

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    cell.imageView.image=img;

    return cell;}
```

Comment: You should edit your question instead with this code. This is not an answer that solve your issue.

Comment: add didSelectRowAtIndexPath Code to this Answer may be problem is within that code!

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubCategory" sender:self];
}   - Thanks for ur reply @Sauurabh Prajapati